# Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005' when adding new site to IIS 7 when driver works for another site?

Tags: iis-7, odbc

I have a site that works as it should with my domain name(lets say it is https://mydoman1.se), and now I want to change the domainname to a new one (https://mydomain2.se) but still have https://mydoman1.se and redirect that to https://mydoman2.se.

So I added a new site(https://mydomain2.se) in the IIS and copied all the setting for the new site from the old site(https://mydomain1.se)
They are both pointing and using the same index.asp page.

I use this Connection:

```
ConnString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER='localhost';Port=3306; DATABASE='db_name'; " &_
"UID='uname';PASSWORD='pwd'; OPTION=3;"
```

If I load https://mydomain1.se it works as it should, but if I load https://mydomain2.se then I get an error that it can´t find the Connection ?

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005' [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] 
Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

I also added a system DSN and when testing it, it connects as it should. So why doesn´t it found it when I know I added it?

I don´t understand why https://mydomain1.se is working and not the new one, they both use the same index file and Connection?

What Im I missing? Does it have anything to do with 32 and 64 system?
Any input really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Could you post your Reverse proxy setting? Besides, have you copied the application pool configurations？Because they are not stored in web.config.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jokies, you pointed me in the right direction. I had to set "Activate 32 bits programs" in the application pool. That was the problem, so you saved my day :-)

Comment: It is appreciated if you could post your answer and accept so that this thread can help other people with similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that solved it was setting "Activate 32 bits programs" in the application pool in the IIS so it found the DSN.

Answer (score 0):

One of our clients has faced the same issue. I have set the Enable 32 bit application to true and that has fixed his issue for the given error.

[image]